# clearing browser's state about localhost:8086

Tags: firefox, browser

I am developing on Linux/Debian/x86-64 an application which runs a specialized Web server using [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) -an HTTP server library- (FWIW, my application is the [MELT monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015), related to the [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) domain specific language to customize GCC).

That application has a web interface, accessible thru  http://localhost:8086/

I'm using a recent Firefox (Debian Iceweasel 38.3) and/or Chrome beta 47.0 as my browser.

<sup>(I could switch to some other *recent* HTML5 conformant browser, if it is easier; I need debugging tools in it)</sup>

During the debugging phase, I constantly need to restart my application and reload some localhost URL... (e.g. http://localhost:8086/hackc.html for example).

Of course, it is much easy to debug such an application if my web browser is in a clean state (no cached data or state related to `localhost:8086`).

Is there **any way to configure my browser** (perhaps thru some addon or whatever extension) **so that clearing all its state related to `localhost:8086`**, in particular cookies and file cache, **is very easy** and convenient? Ideally it would be a button or a menu entry near the browser toolbar! Or perhaps some shell script to clean whatever is relevant inside `~/.mozilla/` ?

Of course I do not want to disturb any other state in my browser (e.g. I certainly don't want to forget cookies logging me to stackoverflow or my corporate webmail...). I only want to clean what is tied to `localhost:8086`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just run a separate browser instance?

Answer (score 1):

If you open windows using chrome's [incognito mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en) your cookies and history will be removed when you close all incognito windows. It doesn't mention * file cache*.

Follow the link to the privacy policy to this paragraph:

> If you use Chrome in incognito mode or guest mode, it will not transmit any pre-existing cookies to sites that you visit. Sites may deposit new cookies on your system while you are in these modes; these cookies will only be temporarily stored and transmitted to sites while you remain in incognito / guest mode. They will be deleted when you close the browser, close all open incognito windows or exit guest mode.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome (I believe Firefox is the same) you have the ability to "hard reload" the current page, you can do this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

This will reload the page ignoring cached data, but the cache will remain and any future reloads/page activity will be affected by the cache.
If you really want to permanently flush the cache *for the current page*  Chrome has an option "Empty Cache and hard reload". To do this, you need to:

- open dev tools (this must be open for it to work)
- click **and hold** the reload button
  [image]
- a menu will appear - select "Empty Cache and hard reload"

Comment: But that won't work for other pages (i.e. opened tabs) in `localhost:8086` ?

Comment: How do you mean? - do you want to clear cache for all web pages loaded in tabs associated with `localhost:8086` in one action?

Comment: Yes, clear all related to `localhost:8086`in one action!

Comment: I think you would need to give the browser a way to group/associate those tabs to a domain - that way you could just use the browser standard "*clear cache for a domain*" option. I would create a named host  config on your webserver that maps your chosen domain to your web apps file path  - and then make an entry for the domain in `/etc/hosts/` - Im assuming if your app works with `localhost:8086` it would work with a named host too

Comment: So you mean browsing `http://localhost.localdomain:8086/` then clearing the entire `.localdomain` domain? And how to do that *easily* without having to open `about:config` ?

Comment: no i mean setup a proper domain.  you w0uld browse to it with `http://basileswebapp.com`  or what ever domain. because its redirected through `/etc/hosts` your browser wont know its really just being hosted locally - then use your broswers normal domain options for clearing cache